# Assigning text to a local variable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Typescript I am trying to read an XML file with some javascript code and add the text content to a local variable with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class JsonreaderService {    

private jsonText: string;

constructor() {
  this.readTextFile("../../assets/content.json");
}

readTextFile(file)
{
  let jsonText: string;
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
      {
        this.jsonText = rawFile.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
}
```

I am trying to assign the text within the json file to my private local variable jsonText: `this.jsonText = rawFile.responseText;` which are both of the type 'string'.

When I try this I get the error:

> Property 'jsonText' does not exist on type 'XMLHttpRequest'

Does somebody know how I can do this within typescript? When I remove `this.` - the responseText can be defined to the jsonText variable which is within the function `readTextFile(file)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: The problemas is that ``this in line `this.jsonText` refers to `rawFile` since it's called from such class. You should apply the typical `self`technique to keep the reference to your own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should hold a reference to class somewhere, like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class JsonreaderService {    

private jsonText: string;

constructor() {
  this.readTextFile("../../assets/content.json");
}

readTextFile(file)
{
  var self = this;
  let jsonText: string;
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
      {
        self.jsonText = rawFile.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
}
```

Comment: You are right! I didn't know or forgot that the 'this' keyword in javascript is not the same as in typescript, java or C# for example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use an arrow function to save the scope of `this`:

```
readTextFile(file)
{
  let jsonText: string;
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = () =>
  {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
      {
        this.jsonText = rawFile.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
```